# Is it possible to list instances with no VPC using Boto get_only_instances()?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

There is an AWS account with instances in a VPC and in the EC2 Classic. I try to list them separately using get_only_instances() method, but it seems that filters doesn't work with not set argument (VPC:None).

```
import boto
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2_connect_to_region('us-east-1', profile_name='qa')
a = conn.get_only_instances(filters={'vpc_id':'vpc-a0876691'})
# len(a) > 0, and should be so
b = conn.get_only_instances(filters={'vpc_id':None})
# len(b) = 0, but should be > 0
```

BTW. I see following approach to work fine:

```
b = [i for i in conn.get_only_instances() if not i.vpc_id]
# len(b) > 0, and should be so
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `get_only_instances` ends up making a call to the [DescribeInstances endpoint in the API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html).

Specifically, Boto will use the filter 'vpc-id', which is stated in the above linked documentation as 'The ID of the VPC that the instance is running in.'

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to query this via Boto to denote a boolean "not" operation.  I'm adding this answer to state that I don't think it's possible.

To work around this, I use a similar approach to yours:

```
import boto
import boto.ec2

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
has_vpc = {'vpc-id': '*'}

r_with_vpc = conn.get_only_instances(filters=instance_filters)
r_all = conn.get_only_instances()


instance_vpc_list = [i.id for i in r_with_vpc]
instance_all = [i.id for i in r_all]

instance_without_vpc = [ i for i in instance_all if i not in instance_vpc_list ]
```

The only real difference being that I build an intermediate list of hosts with *any* vpc set so that I don't need to know the VPC IDs ahead of time.

Comment: im not seeing that get_only_instances is available via boto3.  I see the docs provided here, but that attribute isnt available on any resources so far, cant locate it.  if anybody can, that would be great.  I cant even google `boto3 "get_only_resources" ` nothing is showing up, so much docs on this.